# Possible to have duplicate Google Chrome installed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, kiosk

It is possible to have 2 duplicate Google Chrome install in a machine?

The reason why I need 2 duplicate Google Chrome is because 1 Chrome Application is just for the normal, whereas the other one will import my custom made extension and use it with KIOSK mode to force-redirect to a specific page.

So I know when the KIOSK mode is opened, I couldn't launch the normal Chrome as expected, even though it is possible, I also need to protect the extension being uninstall/disable.

Somehow, I only find this way to secure my custom made extension from being uninstall/disable and also I can create a chrome's shortcut to force-redirect to a specific page.

Thanks for the advanced information. Much appreciate.

**EDIT**

I did tried download & install Google Chrome Portable in local Download dir.
But when I move it to C:/Program File(x86), it will prompt a error message
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8oUg.png). Then If I select YES, the portable browser will be reset. The extension I loaded all lost. Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Portable is the best choice to use.

It won't impact to the original Google Chrome, even thought I install some extension on Chrome Portable, still it won't install to original Google Chrome.

And yet, Chrome Portable is a standalone application. So it can't be launch via Window Search, etc. It is only can be launch via installed folder.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using a sandbox program like [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) or using it as a different user?

Comment: I don't think Sandboxie is the best idea tho

Answer (score 0):

Download [Chromium](https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/en/) and install it, then use it for one of your purposes. It's an unbranded Open Source free-as-in-beer version of Chrome missing very few things (mostly phoning home to Google). It uses the same [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) and [apps](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps) as Chrome does from the same website.

Comment: I and download the Chromium. But where is the application store path? Because I need to create a shortcut to do the kiosk mode then set the permission of the Chromium folder. And also that user can always Window + Chromium to launch the Chromium, then to remove/disable the extension.

Comment: Is there any other Chrome Browser Application that I look into? That could be something like standalone browser application, which is don't need to install or anything. So that user only can use the shortcut other than Window + "Application Name"

Comment: Please kindly review my post updated. I did try Chrome portable.

Comment: _Jack Wong_, it uses the same web store, apps, and extensions as Chromium. Links added to my answer above. I prefer it to Portable Chrome, which is why I did not recommend Portable Chrome.

Comment: You prefer Portable Chrome but you don't recommend Portable Chrome? I am confused. Haha. But anyway, I don't want user can launch the Portable Chrome/Chromium normally other than the shortcut I created. It is possible to do so?

Comment: _Jack Wong_, Chromium is NOT Portable Chrome.